# How to convert list with full name to a tuple of (name,surname) using map

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a problem with converting a list of List(Name Surname, Name Surname, ....) to List((name, surname), (name,surname)).
I've tried to use `map` and `case` but it says that it couldn't find value "+"

```
val lines = io.Source.fromResource("nazwiska.txt").getLines.toList
    println(lines)
    val linesMapped = lines.map{case x+" "+y => (x,y) }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there but try with interpolated string pattern

```
lines.map { case s"$firstname $surname" => (firstname, surname) }
```

also consider switching to `collect` to filter out badly formatted names as mapping above would explode otherwise

```
lines.collect { case s"$firstname $surname" => (firstname, surname) }
```

Comment: Note that it will fail for people who have multiple first and last names, at least common in Latin America like mine :p so you may want to use a **Regex** instead - But, probably for a simple academic exercise it would be an overkill.

Comment: fortunately in my file there are only "simple" names, anyway thank you :)